# App Engine, Codigo de acceso invalido

Tags: java, netbeans, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Estoy desplegando mi proyecto a `Google App Engine`, me pide la autorización y me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esque no se dónde debo colocar ese código. Intente borrar el archivo `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` y volver a desplegar el proyecto pero me da el mismo error. Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando. Estoy usando `NetBeans 8.2` y `Java 8`.

Comment: Es mejor que coloques el código para visualizar mejor tu problema.

Comment: Cómo estás desplegando la aplicación? Utilizando `mvn appengine:deploy`?

Comment: @Yandrak3 hola, no, lo hago directamente desde netbeans. click derecho sobre el proyecto, selecciono "Deploy to Google App Engine",me envia a la pagina para que de permisos, me genera el codigo y me dice que lo pegue en la aplicacion y en netbeans me muestra el error:
Please enter code: Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid_grant

Comment: Netbeans no te muestra algún lugar donde pegar el código que te proporciona la dirección web?

Comment: Es ahi el problema, que no me dice donde.